# ImageDataGenerator dtype doesn't change data type

Tags: python, keras, casting, generator

I'm trying to cast the output data of my `ImageDataGenerator` to integers. This is my generator:

```
train_mask_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10,
                                         width_shift_range=10,
                                         height_shift_range=10,
                                         zoom_range=0.3,
                                         horizontal_flip=True,
                                         vertical_flip=True,
                                         fill_mode='nearest',#interpolation used for augmenting the image
                                         cval=0,
                                         rescale=1./255,
                                         dtype='int32')
```

And then:

```
train_mask_gen = train_mask_data_gen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(training_dir, 'masks'),
                                                     target_size=(img_h, img_w),
                                                     batch_size=bs,
                                                     class_mode=None, # Because we have no class subfolders in this case
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     interpolation='nearest',#interpolation used for resizing
                                                     #color_mode='grayscale',
                                                     seed=SEED)
```

The inputs are binary images(0 or 255 as value), i normalize them and i would like to obtain integer values(for example, each pixel can have only 0 or 1 values).

So far, if i "test" the type of my generated data i obtain `'numpy.float32'` but i wrote `dtype='int32` in my generator.
Seems that the `dtype` entry is completely ignored and i just get the default one (as mentioned in the documentation: [Keras Image Generator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)
Why is this happening? How do i "force" my data to be an integer?

Comment: I have the same problem, I also tried to use `preprocessing_function` that changes the array type but it still doesn't work. This topic was already mentioned in [https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9624] but I found no clear solution.

Comment: @maksym33 i clicked on the link but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Sorry, it seems that one of the squre brackets was added to the link. Here is the pure link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9624

Comment: The issue is still valid for TF 2.4.0rc2

Comment: I still get ```float32``` no matter what I set as ```dtype``` 3 years later...

Comment: @maksym33 How did you use ```preprocessing_function``` to change the array type?

Comment: Still not working !!!!

Comment: Upvote, probably it will get an answer as the question becomes more popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The pressure is high on such old questions, but I will give it a try
> today.

When reviewing the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) of `ImageDataGenerator`, it appears that the `dtype` parameter does not directly affect the data type of the generated images, but defines the:

*"Dtype to use for the generated arrays."*

So the `dtype` parameter in `ImageDataGenerator` is used to set the data type of the internal array that holds the augmented image data before it is returned by the generator. It does not affect the data type of the generated images themselves.

In the case of image data generation, the generated images will still have a data type of `float32`, regardless of the value specified for `dtype` in the generator.

> How do I force my data to be integer?

To achieve integer values in the generated images, you will need to manually convert the generated images to integers after they have been generated.

```py
import numpy as np

# Generate images using the generator
generated_images = train_mask_gen.next()

# Convert the images to integers
generated_images = np.round(generated_images).astype(np.int32)
```